# How do I specify literally a specific type (like str (not instance of str)) in Python with type hinting?

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there a way I can specify a variable should be literally a specific type in Python?

I know that it is possible to specify a variable should a specific type or subtype, but how can I specify only that type?

```
var: str  # instance of string

var: type[str] # subtype or type string

var: (literally str class)  # part in question
```

An example of when this functionality may be necessary pertains to Union types. For example, what if I want the argument passed to a specific parameter of a function or the return type of a function to be literally the type `int` or `str`?

```
def example1(arg: (Literally) int | (Literally) str):
    ...

def example2(arg) -> (Literally) int | (Literally) str:
    ...
```

Comment: Why does this variable exist, if the only value it will ever have is `str`? Why not just use `str` directly?

Comment: @user2357112, simply put, I can use the union functionality with this functionality. (I can specify that an argument of a parameter must be literally the type `int` or `str`). Simply using `Union[int, str]` or `int | str` doesn't work because that specifies an instance of either `int` or `str`.

Comment: That's important information. It means that, for example, `var: Final = str` doesn't do what you need. You should put that in the question.

Comment: examine the `typing` module; this helps create type *hints* for IDEs and such and can alert you to issues.

Comment: typing — Support for type hints
New in version 3.5.

Source code: Lib/typing.py

Note The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to specify a type for your variable you can follow this practice,
before putting any values in your variable, define the variable like this:
string:

```
x = ''
```

list:

```
x = []
```

Dictionary:

```
x = {}
```

and so on ...

Comment: These do not define the variable's type *at all*. They only define one *value*. The variables can still have another type, such as a union, common base, or abstract type that include the value.